# Golang Cerrar channels evitando Panics

Tags: hilos, go, eficiencia

Tengo un dispositivo que se comunica con mi Go Websocket constantemente. Los mensajes que le envío siempre tienen una respuesta, pero a veces el dispositivo toma demasiado tiempo en responder, por lo que hago intentos con un tiempo x como límite. Ahora, a pesar de ello **el dispositivo puede o no responderme luego del tiempo e intentos límite**, esto provoca errores del tipo panic (*panic: send on closed channel*).

**Lo que necesito es poder evitar los panics y usar de forma eficiente los recursos (cerrando los channels y dejando sin referencias a las goroutines para que puedan liberar su memoria luego de que termine la función en la que se encuentran).**

Este código genera panics si el dispositivo me responde luego de 3 intentos de 5 segundos de espera cada uno.

```
resp := make(chan Response, 1)
aux := make(chan int, 1)
var ok Response
// Hilo, que notifica por el canal "aux" la respuesta del dispositivo (ok)
go func() {
    select {
    case ok = <-resp:
        aux <- 4
    }
}()

var i int
for i = 1; i < 4; i++ {
    fmt.Println("Inicia intento n ", i)
    // Hilo, que envia comando y escucha la respuesta del dispositivo
    go func() {
        resp <- ChangeAvailability(data)
    }()
    // Hilo, que detiene re-intentos al recibir respuesta del dispositivo
    go func() {
        i = <-aux
    }()
    // Re-intentos cada x segundos
    <-time.After(15 * time.Second)
}

// Evitando deadlock
close(resp)
close(aux)
// Respuestas hacia el cliente
ManejandoRespuestaCliente(i, ok)
```

Con recover puedo manejar el panic, pero sigue sin ser muy eficiente en el uso de recursos.

No encuentro la lógica que debo implementar para que responda o no el dispositivo luego de x tiempo, pueda cerrar los channels para liberar memoria sin generar panics.

Answer (score 0):

Puesto que el problema es que cierras el `channel` antes de que retorne la función, tienes que asegurarte de no hacerlo.

Para ello lo más sencillo es usar `sync.watigroup`. Aquí llevarás la cuenta de las goroutines que has creado y esperarás a que finalicen. Para saber si una *goroutine* ha finalizado debes llamar al método `wg.Done()` desde la misma:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func worker(data interface{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()  // notificará de la finalización
    resp <- ChangeAvailability(data)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    var i int
    for i = 1; i < 4; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)  // indicamos que tenemos que esperar a la goroutine
        go worker(data, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait() // espera a que todas las goroutines terminen
 
    close(resp)
    close(aux)
}
```

Otra cosa que me parece mejor es usar [Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) para añadir un timeout o cancelar las goroutines y que no intenten escribir en un `channel` cerrado.

Por último, si tienes la posibilidad de modificar la función `ChangeAvailability`, es mejor que solamente cierre un canal quién tenga la responsabilidad sobre él, es decir, para que `ChangeAvailability` utilice un `channel` **que no pueda ser cerrado** por otro proceso, ha de crearlo y cerrarlo la propia función, devolviéndolo al llamante para que pueda leer de él:

```golang
func ChangeAvailability(data interface{}) <-chan Response {
    out := make(chan Response)
    go func() {
        // ... realiza el trabajo y notifica resultados
            out <- Response
        }
        close(out)  // es seguro cerrarlo porque se ha definido en la misma función
    }()

    // devolvemos el canal al llamante para que lo pueda utilizar
    return out
}

// ..... En el llamante...
    go func() {
        out := ChangeAvailability(data)
        for n := range out {
            resp <- n
        }
    }()
// .....
```

Puedes encontrar este artículo interesante: https://blog.golang.org/pipelines